# Client Object Model RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.Remove not working

Tags: client-object-model, permissions

I'm using the Client Object Model and trying to remove a specific RoleDefinition from a `RoleDefinitionBindingCollection` in a RoleAssignment.

This is the code I'm using:

```
        Web web = context.Web;
        List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List");
        context.Load(
            list,
            l => l.RoleAssignments.Include(
                ra => ra.Member,
                ra => ra.RoleDefinitionBindings
                )
            );

        context.ExecuteQuery();

        List<RoleDefinition> toDelete = new List<RoleDefinition>();

        foreach (RoleAssignment ra in list.RoleAssignments) {
            toDelete.Clear();

            foreach (RoleDefinition rd in ra.RoleDefinitionBindings) {
                if (rd.RoleTypeKind == RoleType.Administrator) {
                    toDelete.Add(rd);                        
                }
            }

            if (toDelete.Count > 0) {
                toDelete.ForEach(td => ra.RoleDefinitionBindings.Remove(td));
            }                               
        }

        context.ExecuteQuery();
```

I can see that the `RoleDefinition` is removed from the parent `RoleDefinitionBindings` list, but nothing happens. There is no error and the permissions on the list stays exactly as they were after the `context.ExecuteQuery()`

All the examples I found are showing how to remove an entire RoleAssignment, or how to delete the RoleDefinition from the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `list.Update();` before `context.ExecuteQuery();`

Comment: Nope... still nothing. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following solution:

```
if (list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
{ 
     RoleAssignmentCollection oRoleAssignments = list.RoleAssignments;
     clientContext.Load(oRoleAssignments);
     clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

     foreach (RoleAssignment oRoleAssignment in oRoleAssignments)
     {
            clientContext.Load(oRoleAssignment, r => r.Member, r => r.RoleDefinitionBindings);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Principal oPrincipal = oRoleAssignment.Member;
            if (oPrincipal.LoginName.Equals(userToRemove) || oPrincipal.Title.Equals(userToRemove))
            {
                  foreach (RoleDefinition rd in oRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                  {
                       if (rd.RoleTypeKind == RoleType.Contributor)
                       {
                             clientContext.Load(rd); oRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Remove(rd);
                                    oRoleAssignment.Update();
                                    clientContext.Load(oRoleAssignment, r => r.Member, r => r.RoleDefinitionBindings);
                                    list.Update();
                                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```